# relation between flow rate and frequency response of mobile microphone

Tags: matlab

I have dyson bladeless fan, I'm recording wav files using mobile microphone at different fan levels (I'm measuring fan flow rate using a digital device and recording using mobile simultaneously). I'm trying to find the relation between flow rate and frequency response of mobile microphone. In matlab I should do the processing for wav files. my question: what is the best normalization in my case. Shall I do the normalization in time domain (before fft) or in frequency domain (after fft), the purpose of normalization is to compare the recorded audios regardless the loudness of the fan while recording since fan sound increases at higher levels and we should compare the air flow not the loudness of the fan.

Comment: I'm afraid to say that _all_ questions containing the phrase "What is the best..." will get closed as opinion based.

Comment: I mean what do you think the best.., so it is opinion based and I will try all suggested opinions and decide depending on the results

Comment: Unfortunately, opinion based questions are not welcome on SO. If you manage to ask this question in a way that makes it possible to answer it objectively then you might get an answer, but as it is now, I'm afraid you won't get much help.